# Broker Database - Unable to retrieve htm files from DB

Tags: dd4t, broker, database

I have the following configuration to save files to the broker Database.

```
<Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>  
<Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".sitemap" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
<Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".css" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
<Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".js" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>    
<Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultFile" cached="false"/>
<Item typeMapping="Metadata" cached="false" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>  
<Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".xml" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
<Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".config" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
```

I have published an html page `/page/test.htm`, the file is getting saved to the database but I am unable to view it when hitting `domain.com/page/test` or `domain.com/page/test.htm`

I have the deployer and website configured with the above cd_storage configuration. Has any one faced similar issue like this?

Comment: What is the storage configuration of `defaultDataFile`? According to the standard defaults, this would point to a File System location for your metadata, NOT a database. Actually, it doesn't look like you're publishing to the database at all.

Comment: `defaultDataFile` has configuration to SQL database. The files are getting saved with file extension .htm.

Comment: Can you find the published page in the broker db? There should be a record for it in the ITEMS table.

Comment: Yes files are there at DB. It is present in `PAGES` also at 'ITEMS` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking with alternate file extensions. It seems the issue is with the retrieval end rather than publishing end.

`Solution: The dll files needs to be updated with code to enable retrieval of .htm files.`